# Can't Login to phpmyadmin without using password

Tags: arch-linux, phpmyadmin

I would like to logging into phpmyadmin without using password.

However I changed `AllowNoPassword` to `TRUE` in `/etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

But, phpmyadmin asks me for password again!

**P.S:**

MySQL `root` user has no password.

Comment: did you reastart service after the changing of configuration

Comment: Yes I did that.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested at [Archlinux BBS](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=115625): add `/etc/webapps` to `open_basedir` in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

first, stop apache before editing this file with this:

```
/etc/init.d/apache stop
```

then, if you are trying to log in as root, you should have the following lines in your config:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';# add this line
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

finally, start apache again:

```
/etc/init.d/apache start
```

Comment: I added `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';` line. But doesn't work!